# Is an Ubuntu server the best option for me?

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I am currently tasked with the process of creating a file server for a small business I work at. My boss is keen on the fact that we can create an Ubuntu server for free and has put the task to me. I really don't have much knowledge of Linux and have everyone in the office uses Windows as their OS.

Basically what the question I am asking is if Ubuntu is a good choice for a small business server, where all of the users in the office have Windows operating systems. We already have a server in the office that uses Windows server 2008, so everyone can connect to that easily just by mapping network drives. My fear however is that if we switch to an Linux server, connecting to the server wont be as easy as it is with a windows server, as apparently the only way to do this is with PuTTy. Can anybody help weigh in on what I should do?

Edit: The Linux server will eventually replace the windows server once we have migrated all the files across. The linux server will have RAID 5 for better data security and will have more space available that the current windows server. It will eventually be used as web server too once everything is running smoothly, however our first priority is to get it working and connected locally.

Comment: side question: Is it possible once the server is up and running for Windows computers to map it?

Comment: Is the linux server to replace the Windows server (eventually)? What is the purpose for the Linux server? To hold data files? Use as a email server? Use as a web server? Please provide as much info as you can.

Comment: Yes the Linux server will eventually replace the windows server once we have migrated all the files across. The linux server will have RAID 5 for better data security and will have more space available that the current windows server. It will eventually be used as  web server too once everything is running smoothly, however our first priority is to get it working and connected locally.

Comment: Does anyone in the whole shop know anything about Unix/Linux/Ubuntu and, I suppose, technical details about your current (Windows) environment? You may be about to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: Yeah that's my worry too, everyone is running windows 8 and most of the people in the office are a bit technophobic, so if accessing the server on a windows computer isn't easy or is more of a hassle than just opening  a mapped network drive I think this may be a bad idea. Thoughts?

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: Running a Linux server is not the same as windows, and it depends on your experience with Linux. Ubuntu is not the only option and for the most part your question is more an opinion the "fact"

Comment: The issue here isn't it being more difficult for your end users to connect and make use of the file shares, the issue is you or someone else being able to correctly configure the Ubuntu server and Samba to enable your windows users to connect.  There are web-based front ends to make configuration easier, but you may not want to jump right into to making this new system live on the network or encourage people to use it until you fully understand configuration and have successfully run backups and restores of the data on the system so that when you do switch over some of the risk is mitigated.

Answer (score 2):

I do not advise. if you are not familiar with Ubuntu you will have a hell of a time trying to diagnose issues. I am a tech and I use Linux and Ubuntu server and I will not use Ubuntu as a file server just because of diagnostic issues.. ( i am a novice user) if i were a pro, that would be a different story.. tell your boss that the risk will not be worth the reward.

I can think of so many situations I've had with clients that Ubuntu would not be able to solve.

Answer (score 2):

The old saying "Linux is free if your time has no value" applies here. Unless you already know it well, the answer is basically no. It starts to pay dividends as your business grows or to the extent you have knowledgeable people around, particularly if you're a tech business. For a small business where you want your computer system to mostly do a few simple things without much difficulty, it's asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is the "askUbuntu" forum, but I must say after working with both linux and FreeNAS, that you will have a much easier time managing your storage with FreeNAS ( http://freenas.org ) . It looks just like network appliance rather than a server, but it is 100% server.

If you want to do it right, you need to read the FAQ about hardware, etc. It is a software raid that needs a lot of memory. The performance is great, though. Also, by default, it uses redundancy that will tolerate 2 disk failures (like raid 6).

The nice thing about it is that all of your control is through a web interface and you need not learn any unix or linux. It will also serve out multiple protocols like iscsi, rsync, nfs, ftp, cifs (windows share).

For example, I was running out of free disk space. All I had to do was point my browser at the server, log in, and change the quota on the share. I went from 3.2 Tb to 5 Tb in 2 seconds.

Comment: FreeNAS is not the alternate to Ubuntu, Fedora also has a web interface. RHEL and SUSE are , IMO , also options as alternates to Ubuntu. See http://cockpit-project.org/ and https://liquidat.wordpress.com/2014/02/11/first-look-at-cockpit-a-web-based-server-management-interface/

Comment: cockpit is available on Arch , RHEL, Centos, and Fedora and " The interface is slick and easy to use, for simple server setups it could come in handy as a server management tool for example for beginners ..."

Comment: Thanks @bodhi.zazen . It is good to know there are linux distros with easy to manage storage solutions. While zfs's "scrub" function protects against silent data corruption ( see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_corruption#SILENT ) and zfs is also available under ubuntu, better RAID controllers will also check for corruption as well.

Answer (score 1):

It took me around 50 hours probably to get comfortable with Ubuntu Server, but I am a techie, but I loved it once I got into it. Windows Server = $$$$, ask for a bonus or raise etc and help keep the money inside the company!

PS: Windows can easily access linux via protocols such as SAMBA (CIFS), WebDav (Look up Owncloud) and Win 7 Ult and Win 8.1 Enterprise have NFS mount abilities.

SAMBA is only usable internally on the LAN, so for remote access need VPN, OpenVPN is good solution, and OPEN SOURCE AND FREE!

WebDav is great for remote access for windows as it has built in support, A simple .cmd file in startup folder can map WebDav Directorys to a drive letter on startup, great for sending to employee's who are not technically inclined.

The biggest reason I would maybe go Windows is Email, I have yet to successfully get email on my server as it requires multiple programs to be configured to work together where windows will be much easier in that sense.

Answer (score 1):

> My fear however is that if we switch to an Linux server, connecting to the server wont be as easy as it is with a windows server, as apparently the only way to do this is with PuTTy

Samba fixes that for you.

Ubuntu server using it as a file server is rather easy: all you need to do is install the file-server task. It will install all you need (`sudo apt-get install tasksel`, start it with `tasksel` and pick "samba file server".

All the rest is configuration and that can be done with a how-to or by searching AskUbuntu. [This is a how-to on Samba](http://www.allaboutlinux.eu/how-to-install-samba-server-on-ubuntu/): it is 1 config file you need to setup.

If you are willing to learn about maintaining a Linux file server: go for it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, CentOS would be the distribution typically used in enterprise and business environments.

https://www.centos.org/

However, if you still plan on using Ubuntu, Ubuntu Server would be the lightest coming out of the box, and should be the one you use.

If you absolutely need a GUI, then you can either install the Gnome Desktop Environment with `apt-get install gnome-desktop-environment`, or simply use the Desktop version of Ubuntu; and use the Package Manager to install and configure the Samba service to let your Windows machines mount to it.

Comment: Given the changes to CentOS recently, there's been a large number of people who have been shifting away due to SystemD and the large number of command changes done in the latest release - the statement that CentOS would be typically used is therefore unsubstantiated and potentially outright wrong.